# Adding to default classes in a macro

Tags: templating, craft3, macro

I'm fairly new to using macros and haven't found anything online regarding this — sorry if this is a possible duplicate post.

I've created a macro with 7 possible parameters but on different templates I want to add to the default classes.

```
{% macro button(label, link, width , classes, colours, textclasses, alignment) %}
  <a href="{{ link }}" class="btn {{ width|default('w5') }} {{ colours|default('bg-tdgreen white') }} {{ classes|default('flex pa2 pa3-ns ph3 tc lh-solid f7 f6-ns link underline-hover z-999 br2 mv3 tracked-more') }} {{ alignment|default('center') }}">
    <p class="ttu center mv0 {{ textclasses|default('') }}">{{ label }}</p>
  </a>
{% endmacro %}
```

Is there a way of doing this without having to set a variable with all the defaults in it and tacking on new classes? For example:

```
{% set buttonClasses = "absolute w5-ns l-50 tc pa2 pa3-ns ph3 br2 z-max link white f6 flex mt--18 mt--25-ns underline-hover tracked-more" %}
  {% if buttonPosition == 'above' %}
    {% set buttonClasses = buttonClasses ~ " top-0" %}
  {% endif %}
{{ macros.button(block.ctaText, block.ctaLink.one().url, "", buttonClasses) }}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

— Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tons of ways to skin this cat; a simple option is to use [string concatenation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7704253/how-to-concatenate-strings-in-twig), which could look like the below example. Note that I'm actually creating a new variable for `classes` at the top of the macro, which IMO helps clean up the markup a little bit and also makes it a bit more clear what's going on – you can continue to do this logic "inline" if you want to, of course.

Also note that the `default` filter has been omitted from the Twig statement rendering the `classes` variable; it's redundant now because the `classes` variable will always be set.

```
{% macro button(label, link, width, classes, colours, textclasses, alignment) %}
    {% set classes = 'flex pa2 pa3-ns ph3 tc lh-solid f7 f6-ns link underline-hover z-999 br2 mv3 tracked-moreflex pa2 pa3-ns ph3 tc lh-solid f7 f6-ns link underline-hover z-999 br2 mv3 tracked-more' ~ (classes ? ' ' ~ classes) %}
    <a href="{{ link }}" class="btn {{ width|default('w5') }} {{ colours|default('bg-tdgreen white') }} {{ classes }} {{ alignment|default('center') }}">
        <p class="ttu center mv0 {{ textclasses|default('') }}">{{ label }}</p>
    </a>
{% endmacro %}
```

The important bit is the `... ~ (classes ? classes)` part, which basically appends the `classes` macro parameter to the default classnames, if the parameter is set.

A variation on the above solution, and – in my opinion – maybe a bit cleaner, is to use an array that is joined (i.e. flattened to a string):

```
{% macro button(label, link, width, classes, colours, textclasses, alignment) %}{% macro button(label, link, width, classes, colours, textclasses, alignment) %}
    {% set classes = ['flex pa2 pa3-ns ph3 tc lh-solid f7 f6-ns link underline-hover z-999 br2 mv3 tracked-moreflex pa2 pa3-ns ph3 tc lh-solid f7 f6-ns link underline-hover z-999 br2 mv3 tracked-more', classes]|filter|join(' ') %}
    ...
{% endmacro %}
```

Basically, in the above the `classes` *variable* is an array containing the default classes and whatever was passed in the `classes` *parameter*. The array is piped through the [`filter`](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/filters.html#filter) Twig filter, which removes any null/undefined values (i.e. it removes the `classes` parameter value if one wasn't set), and finally [`join(' ')`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/join.html) which merges the two array values together with a space (which means it's now a string and you can do `{{ classes }}` to print the whole thing).

Comment: Ah, this is perfect and exactly what I was looking for. It definitely makes a lot more sense (and is much cleaner) doing it this way. Thanks so much!